# An error occurred (InvalidSubnetID.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances operation: The subnet ID 'subnet-xxxxxxx' does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm running the below command

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxx  --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name xxxxxxxx.pem --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxx --region us-east-1 --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx
```

I have copied and pasted all values direct from the console.  The error message says that my subnet doesn't exist but it does.  Please advise.

Comment: Try to launch the instance in a different subnet, and see if you are able to. Also,
make sure the region is correct.

Comment: I tried with a different subnet and got the same error message.  I checked and the region is correct.

Comment: Are you able to launch using the console? Check in the CloudTrail to see if you get any detailed error message.
Also, how are you passing credentials to the instance, using the Instance profile or the CLI (aws configure).

One more thing you can try is to force giving the region in command, using "--region"

Comment: I can absolutely launch an AMI at the console.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue only via ansible. Essentially the issue was with accesskey and secret key, before creating ec2 instance the client needs to verify the existence of subnet for which it would need access to access key.